# Tratamento de erro não está ocorrendo

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

No código abaixo eu tratei o erro só que após tratar ele ainda aparece o nome quantidade (mandei a foto abaixo para facilitar o entendimento). Como faço para ele não mostrar o nome quantidade? Também gostaria de saber se caso ocorresse uma exceção o usuário tivesse outra chance de escrever o preço novamente.

```
    System.out.println("NOME DO PRODUTO: ");
    produto.setNome(entrada.next().trim().replace(" ", "").toUpperCase());
    try {
    System.out.print("PREÇO: ");
    produto.setPreco(entrada.nextDouble());
    }catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("ERRO");
    }
    System.out.print("QUANTIDADE: ");
    item.setQuantidade(entrada.nextInt());
```

[image: erro ocorrendo no código]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que colocar todo o código que deseja que seja tratado dentro do `try`, o que está fora não tem essa "proteção" e quebra a aplicação.

```
System.out.println("NOME DO PRODUTO: ");
produto.setNome(entrada.next().trim().replace(" ", "").toUpperCase());
try {
    System.out.print("PREÇO: ");
    produto.setPreco(entrada.nextDouble());
    System.out.print("QUANTIDADE: ");
    item.setQuantidade(entrada.nextInt());
} catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print("ERRO");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/InputMismatchException.java).

Provavelmente tem outros problemas nesse código e há ineficiências visíveis, mas aí para ver tudo isso precisaria ver como realmente a programação funciona, não pode ser na tentativa e erro.